# Android-Unable to add support library to a project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android apps. I am trying to add support library to a project. I have right clicked my 'project', then I had gone to 'android tools' and then 'add support library'.

I had checked other posts and have enabled android sdk manager to be run as a 'administrator'.

I had already through android sdk have installed android support library. Is it because of this reason, I am unable to add the support library to the project. If so if we install through android sdk once we need not install for individual projects.

```
[2013-09-08 15:52:32 - SDK Manager]   URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\support_r18.zip (Access is denied)
```

Comment: Raj, when you installed the SDK did you encounter any errors? The support library (or libraries) should be in `$SDK_LOCATION/extras/android/support/vX/android-support-vX.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Just run eclipse on administrator mode. This work to me.